# Метод item() не работает

Tags: javascript

Начинаю изучать JavaScript по книге Дакетта от издания 2017 года.
В разделе про массивы там указано следующее:

[image: Отрывок из книги про извлечение данных из массива]

Пытаюсь воспроизвести этот код на странице, но получаю следующую ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: colors.item is not a function
> at test.js:3:27

Интересно, что если посмотреть на этот пример в файлах, которые идут к дополнению к книге, то можно увидеть немного другой код, который уже работает:

```
var colors = new Array('белый', 'черный', 'пользовательский');
var el = document.getElementById('colors');
el.textContent = colors[0];
```

Вопрос следующий: почему не работает метод item() из примера из книги?

Comment: Метод `item` отсутствует у массива(`Array`)

Comment: В книге ошибка?

Comment: пока не ясно ошибка ли или нет. может где-то и правда существовал метод такой... но вот сейчас везде проверяю в доках и поисковике - нигде упоминания нет.....вот такое нашёл https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection/item   но это HTMLCollection  а не массив.   ..... и ещё NodeList https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_nodelist_item.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Текст в книги и правильный и неправильный одновременно. Првильно то, что метод `item` есть. Но имеется он не у массивов, а у коллекций (объекты, ведущие себя **подобно массиву**), например

**[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** и **[HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection/item)**

А неправильно то, что автор, видимо, путает массивы и коллекции.

---

Может быть до 2017 у массивов были эти методы (не смог найти инфу). Сейчас это точно не так.

Comment: Про коллекции пока ничего не знаю. Насколько понял, в книге идёт речь о массивах.
Получается var colors = new Array это создание коллекции?

Comment: Автор либо напутал, либо не разбирается в теме, либо раньше  ̶т̶р̶а̶в̶а̶ ̶б̶ы̶л̶а̶ ̶з̶е̶л̶е̶н̶е̶е̶  было по-другому

Comment: new Array  - создание массива нотацией создания через объект (разница между созданием new Array  и [] есть, т.к. доступны разные методы....но item всё равно ни там ни там нет)

Answer (score 1):

У массива(`Array`) нет метода `item`. Чтобы получить, например 3 элемент массива, вы можете воспользоваться литералом массива `[2]` или методом `at(2)` (Только в последней версии ES2022)

```js
var colors = new Array('белый', 'черный', 'пользовательский');
document.getElementById('colorWithArrayLiteral').textContent = colors[1];
document.getElementById('colorWithAt').textContent = colors.at(2);
```

```html
<div id="colorWithArrayLiteral"></div>
<div id="colorWithAt"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. У вас опечатка в коде JS на второй строчке:
colors[1] вместо colors[2]

Comment: @NDMX Я для примера разные индексы взял